# Jensen's inequality for integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

What nice ways do you know in order to prove Jensen's inequality for integrals? I'm looking for some various approaching ways.
Supposing that $\varphi$ is a convex function on the real line and $g$ is an integrable real-valued function we have that:

$$\varphi\left(\int_a^b f\right) \leqslant \int_a^b \varphi(f).$$

Comment: And by Jensen's inequality, do you mean something about convex functions?  And not http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula

Comment: @GEdgar: i know that in English is called Jensen's inequality for integrals (i hope i'm not wrong) and is related to convex functions.

Comment: @Chris: That reply does not really clarify what you mean. Why not just edit your question such that it explicitly quotes the statement you want a proof of?

Comment: @Henning Makholm: right. I hope it's better now.

Comment: Do you have that $b-a=1$?

Comment: @robjohn: i think you're right. b-a=1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all, Jensen's inequality requires a domain, $X$, where
$$
\int_X\,\mathrm{d}\mu=1\tag{1}
$$
Next, suppose that $\varphi$ is convex on the convex hull of the range of $f$, $\mathcal{K}(f(X))$; this means that for any $t_0\in \mathcal{K}(f(X))$,
$$
\frac{\varphi(t)-\varphi(t_0)}{t-t_0}\tag{2}
$$
is non-decreasing for $t\in\mathcal{K}(f(X))\setminus\{t_0\}$. This means that we can find a $\Phi$ so that
$$
\sup_{t<t_0}\frac{\varphi(t)-\varphi(t_0)}{t-t_0}\le\Phi\le\inf_{t>t_0}\frac{\varphi(t)-\varphi(t_0)}{t-t_0}\tag{3}
$$
and therefore, for all $t$, we have
$$
(t-t_0)\Phi\le\varphi(t)-\varphi(t_0)\tag{4}
$$
Now, let $t=f(x)$ and set
$$
t_0=\int_Xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu\tag{5}
$$
and $(4)$ becomes
$$
\left(f(x)-\int_Xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)\Phi\le\varphi(f(x))-\varphi\left(\int_Xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)\tag{6}
$$
Integrating both sides of $(6)$ while remembering $(1)$ yields
$$
\left(\int_Xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu-\int_Xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)\Phi\le\int_X\varphi(f(x))\,\mathrm{d}\mu-\varphi\left(\int_Xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)\tag{7}
$$
which upon rearranging, becomes
$$
\varphi\left(\int_Xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)\le\int_X\varphi(f(x))\,\mathrm{d}\mu\tag{8}
$$

Comment: You are also taking $x=f(x)$, which is a confusing notation.

Comment: @MTurgeon: I have changed to $t=f(x)$.

Comment: @robjohn I corrected a small typo that had me scratching my head for a few moments. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Potato: thanks. That was a residual error from the previous edit.

Comment: @robjohn would any steps in the proof change if $\varphi$ was convex on $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @cap: I don't think this proof is easily extended to multiple dimensions; it is very one-dimensional. However, if a multidimensional function is convex in each variable separately, then one should be able to apply Jensen one variable at a time.

Comment: Why does $\Phi$ for $t_0$ exist? Don’t you need $f(X) \subseteq [a, b] \subseteq (c, d)$ and $\phi$ is convex on $[c, d]$?

Comment: The left side of $(3)$ is $\le$ the right side. Thus, a $\Phi$ exists, but it may not be unique.

Comment: Right before $(2)$ we have $t_0\in f(X)$ and then, at $(5)$, $t_0 = \int_Xf$, which may not belong in $f(X)$. The actual requirement for $t_0$ is to be in the domain of $\varphi$. So, what is missing here is the reason why the integral of $f$ is in the domain of $\varphi$.

Comment: Because $\int_X1\,\mathrm{d}x=1$, it seems we need to extend the convexity of $\varphi$ to the convex hull of $f(X)$ for full generality.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for reviewing your answer. Please, take a look at the [clarification](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3656295/269050) I just added.

Comment: @Matematleta: what mistake did you correct?

Comment: @Matematleta: Ah, that just showed up an hour ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

One way would be to apply the finite Jensen's inequality
$$\varphi\left(\frac{\sum a_i x_i}{\sum a_j}\right) \le \frac{\sum a_i \varphi (x_i)}{\sum a_j}$$
to each Riemann sum. The finite inequality is itself easily proved by induction on the number of points, using the definition of convexity.

Answer (score 9):

I like this, maybe it is what you want ...

Let $E$ be a separable Banach space, let $\mu$ be a probability measure defined on $E$, let $f : E \to \mathbb R$ be convex and (lower semi-)continuous.  Then
$$
f\left(\int_E x d\mu(x)\right) \le \int_E f(x)\,d\mu(x) .
$$
Of course we assume $\int_E x d\mu(x)$ exists, say for example $\mu$ has bounded support.

For the proof, use Hahn-Banach.  Write $y = \int_E x d\mu(x)$.  The super-graph $S=\{(x,t) : t \ge f(x)\}$ is closed convex.  (Closed, because $f$ is lower semicontinuous; convex, because $f$ is convex.)  So for any $\epsilon > 0$ by Hahn-Banach I can separate $(y,f(y)-\epsilon)$ from $S$.  That is, there is a continuous linear functional $\phi$ on $E$ and a scalar $s$ so that $t \ge \phi(x)+s$ for all $(x,t) \in S$ and $\phi(y)+s > f(y)-\epsilon$.  So:
$$
f(y) -\epsilon < \phi(y)+s = \phi\left(\int_E x d\mu(x)\right)+s =
\int_E (\phi(x)+s) d\mu(x) < \int_E f(x) d\mu(x) .
$$
This is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, so we have the conclusion.

[image: diagram]

Comment: If $\phi$ is a continuous linear functional on $E$, how do we define $\phi(y)$ (I assumed $y$ is in $\mathbb{R}$)? Thanks

Comment: @Xiao ... no, here $x,y$ are in $E$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a nice proof:

**Step 1**: Let $\varphi$ be a convex function on the interval $(a,b)$.  For $t_0\in (a,b)$, prove that there exists $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi(t)-\varphi(t_0)\geq\beta(t-t_0)$ for all $t\in(a,b)$.

**Step 2**: Take $t_0=\int_a^bfdx$ and $t=f(x)$, and integrate with respect to $x$ to prove the desired inequality.

Comment: There needs to be something about $b-a=1$ or else this doesn't work.

Comment: @robjohn Of course. To be honest, I thought the OP took this as an "invisible assumption"

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/171625/269050) assumes that the integral belongs in the domain of $\varphi$, i.e.,
$$
    \int_X\!f(x)\;dx \tag{1} \in {\rm dom}(\varphi)
$$
Even more, the statement we want to prove involves the evaluation of $\varphi$ at the value of the integral. So, a question remains: **why does $(1)$ hold?**

Let $a<b$ be the ends of the interval $I$ where $\varphi$ is defined (they may or may not belong to $I$). In order to show $(1)$ we need a hypothesis, namely
$$
    \int_{\{f\notin I\}}dx = 0, \tag2
$$
i.e., $f\in I\rm\ a.e.$ (which does happen if $f(X)\subseteq{\rm dom}(\varphi)=I$)

Because of hypothesis $(2)$, to prove $(1)$ it is enough to show
$$
    \int_{\{f \in I\}}f(x)\;dx \in I.
$$
Since
$$
    1 = \int_X dx = \int_{\{f\in I\}}dx + \int_{\{f\notin I\}}dx
         = \int_{\{f\in I\}}dx,
$$
we obtain
$$
    a = \int_{\{f\in I\}} a\;dx \le \int_{\{f\in I\}}f(x)\;dx
$$
Now, assume $a\notin I$ and
$$
    \int_{\{f\in I\}} f(x)\;dx = \int_Xf(x)\;dx = a.\tag3
$$
Then we would also have
$$
    \int_{\{f \ge a\}}f(x)\;dx = \int_{\{f\in I\}}f(x)\;dx = a
        = \int_{\{f\ge a\}}a\,dx.\tag4
$$
But $(4)$ means that $f = a,\rm\ a.e.$, which contradicts our hypothesis because $a\notin I$.

Thus $\int_X f(x)\,dx=a$ and $a\in I$ or $\int_X f(x)\,dx > a$. Similarly, $\int_X f(x)\,dx=b$ and $b\in I$ or $\int_X f(x)\,dx < b$.

In any case $(1)$ does hold and we can proceed as in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/171625/269050) of reference.

Comment: It looks as if you are showing that $\int_Xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\in\mathcal{K}(f(X))$.

Comment: @robjohn It depends on your hypothesis because ${\cal K}(f(X))$ could be "artificially" enlarged by means of a set of measure zero. This is why I've chosen the weaker assumption that $\{f\notin I\}$ has measure $0$. Not a big deal anyway, I just wanted to clarify your answer a little further.