# holomorphic on unit disk, then $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left|f\left(re^{i\theta}\right)\right|^{p}d\theta\geq\left|f\left(0\right)\right|^{p}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\left\{ z\in\mathbb{C}:\left|z\right|<1\right\} $ and $0<r<1$. Then for every $p>0$: $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left|f\left(re^{i\theta}\right)\right|^{p}d\theta\geq\left|f\left(0\right)\right|^{p}$$

I solved for two cases, the first is when $p=1$ and we get the inequality by Cauchy integral formula. the second, is where $f$ not vanishing on the open disk. then $f$ can be written as $f\left(z\right)=e^{g\left(z\right)}$, and again applying Cauchy formula for $f^{p}$.
I was told that the general case can be proven using those cases, yet I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I think you are missing a factor of $\frac1  {2\pi}$ on the left.

Comment: Indeed, fixed. thanks for noticing.

Comment: For $p \geq 1$ this follows by Mean Value Property of analytic functions and Holder's inequality. I doubt its validity for $0<p<1$.

Comment: It follows because $|f|^p$ is subharmonic for every $p>0$ when $f$ is holomoprhic, so the submean property in discs holds; more generally the integrals above increase with $r$ for a fixed $p>0$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3406949/42969