# Proof that the following family of functions is normal

Tags: complex-analysis

currently I am trying to solve the following exercise where I need to show that the following family is normal:
$$
\mathcal{F} = \{f \colon \mathbb D \to \mathbb C : f \text{ is analytic and } \int_{\mathbb D} |f(x+iy)| dx dy \leq 1\}.
$$

**My try**: By the theory of complex analysis it is enough to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally uniformly bounded. Thus take arbitary $f \in \mathcal{F}$ and any $z_0 \in \mathbb D$, take $r < 1-|z_0|$ then since $f$ is analytic it satisfies the mean value property hence
$$
|f(z_0)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0 |f(z_0+re^{i\theta})| d\theta,
$$
now integrate everything with respect to $r$ yields that
$$
r |f(z_0)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{r}_0 \int^{2\pi}_{0} |f(z_0+re^{i\theta})| d\theta \, ds,
$$
now using the co-area formula yields one has
$$
r |f(z_0)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{C_r(z_0)} |f(x+iy)| dx dy \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb D} |f(x+iy)| dx dy \leq \frac{1}{2\pi},
$$
but rearranging yields a uniform bound for $f$ since $r$ is only dependent on $z_0$. Since $z_0 \in \mathbb D$ was arbitary we just showed that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally uniformly bounded and hence normal.

**Question**: Is the abuse of the co-area formula correct here, intuitively this seems to make sense since we integrate over all smaller balls inside $D_{r}(z_0)$ but maybe one can write it more precise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small error since
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{B_r(z_0)} |f(x+iy)| dx dy = 
 \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{r}_0 \int^{2\pi}_{0} |f(z_0+re^{i\theta})| s \, d\theta \, ds \, ,
$$
the factor $s$ (which is the Jacobian determinant of the tranformation from cartesian to polar coordinates) is missing in your calculation.

But that is easily fixed: Multiplying
$$
|f(z_0)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0 |f(z_0+re^{i\theta})| d\theta \, ,
$$
with $s$ and integrating with respect to $s$ from $0$ to $r$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
 \frac 12 r^2 |f(z_0)| &\leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{r}_0 \int^{2\pi}_{0} |f(z_0+re^{i\theta})| s \, d\theta \, ds \\
 &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{B_r(z_0)} |f(x+iy)| dx dy \\
 &\le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\Bbb D} |f(x+iy)| dx dy \\
&\le \frac{1}{2\pi}
\end{align}
$$
and therefore
$$
 |f(z_0)| \le \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \, .
$$

Comment: I have used $B_r(z_0)$ to denote the ball (disk) with center $z_0$ and radius $r$, and not $C_r(z_0)$ which I associate with a *circle.*

Comment: you are correct that is the better notation to not use $C_r(z_0)$ and the rest is now also clear now. The results still should hold true if one has higher power in the inequality with respect to the funtion, i.e. $\int_{\mathbb D} |f(x+iy)|^{p} dx dy \leq 1$ right?

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent: Yes, because $|f(z_0)|^p \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0 |f(z_0+re^{i\theta})|^p d\theta $ holds for all $p > 0$. For *integers* $p$ one can use that $f^p$ is holomorphic. For the general case one needs that $|f(z)|^p$ is subharmonic for all $p > 0$, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3406949/42969.

Comment: Very cool thank you a lot for the reference !