# Which is greater - $\int_0^1\frac{1}{f(x)}dx$ or $\bigg(\int_0^1f(x)dx\bigg)^{-1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measureable function and let $1<c<\infty$ , so $$c^{-1}\le f(x)\le c$$  for every $x \in [0,1]$ .

Let:
$$\alpha=\int_0^1\frac{1}{f(x)}dx$$
$$\beta=\bigg(\int_0^1f(x)dx\bigg)^{-1}$$

Which is greater $\alpha$ or $\beta$ ?

=============================================================

After setting some specific simple functions, it seems that $\alpha$ is greater.

So I first tried to prove it for some simple function $f=\sum_{j=1}^N\alpha_j\chi_{E_j}$ , where $\{E_j\}$ are pairwise disjoint, $[0,1]=\bigcup_{j=1}^{N} E_j$ and  $c^{-1}\le \alpha_j \le c$  for every $j$.

Also $\frac{1}{f}=\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{\alpha_j}\chi_{E_j}$,  and $c^{-1}\le \frac{1}{\alpha_j} \le c$  for every $j$.

However, from this point any inequation I tried led me to the obvious result which is $c^{-1}\le \alpha, \beta \le c$ .

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Since $\phi(x)=1/x$ is convex for $x>0$, you can apply [Jensen's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171599/jensens-inequality-for-integrals)

Comment: Yes, I know C-S. Didn't think about using it, since this specific course does not cover Hilbert spaces. Didn't know about this version of Jensen's inequality. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: as $f(x) \ge c^{-1}>0$, just apply the [Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2):

$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta} = \bigg(\int_0^1f(x)dx\bigg)\bigg(\int_0^1\frac{1}{f(x)}dx\bigg) \ge \left(\int_0^1\sqrt{f(x)}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{f(x)}}dx \right)^2 = 1$$

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!